# How to set Thunderbird3 as default email client?

Tags: windows-xp, thunderbird

Right now I have Thunderbird2 set as default mail client, but I would like to use Thunderbird3, how to do it?

Comment: This has nothing to do with firefox, does it?

Comment: @rems why? thunderbird is email client of firefox.

Comment: No, they're two completely separate programs. (You might be thinking of Mozilla Suite, which _does_ have the browser and the mail client in a single program.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Uninstall Thunderbird 2. Your mail will not be removed.
- In Thunderbird 3, open *Tools → Options → Advanced → General* and click on *System Integration → Check Now*.

  This will ask if you want to make Tb3 the default client for mail.

---

By default, all versions of Mozilla Thunderbird keep your settings in `%APPDATA%\Thunderbird\Profiles\`. The profile directory is *never* removed when uninstalling (only if you manually go and delete it), but if you're still afraid, make a copy of it.

(In Windows XP, `%APPDATA%` usually is `C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\Application Data\`)

Answer (score 0):

Just install it and it should work. Or do you mean you installed it already and it does not work as your default mail client?

Do you have both Thunderbird2 and Thunderbird3 installed? If so then deinstall Thunderbird2 !

Comment: I have both. Im scared of uninstalling the v.2 because it might remove my emails :/

Comment: @IAdapter: Uninstalling Thunderbird _will not_ remove your data.

Comment: It shouldn't remove anything of your mails or configuration, this are all stored with your user Documents, but if you want to be sure just make a copy of the thunderbird folder to somewhere else.